# Webforms: HttpModule or HttpHandler to save info in the cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, httphandler, httpmodule

I would like to store some information in the cache that I can compare later on with those that the user has typed in. Should I use HttpModule or HttpHandler?? Or is there any better way to do this in WebForms?? I know that in MVC ActionFilters can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use session state:

```
// Save to session state in a Web Forms page class.
Session["FirstName"] = firstName;
Session["LastName"] = lastName;
Session["City"] = city;

// Read from session state in a Web Forms page class.
firstName = (string)(Session["FirstName"]);
lastName = (string)(Session["LastName"]);
city = (string)(Session["City"]);
```